# How to get auto increment id after save in Yii2

Tags: yii2

Im trying to get auto increment id after save in Yii2.I tried to the following code block but its not working.

```
public function actionAddgroup()
{
    $model = new Groups();
    $model->groupName=Yii::$app->request->post('groupName');

    $model->save();  // a new row is inserted into user table
    return $model->id;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Where you are trying to return the `$model->id` immediately after creating a new `Groups` instance, the `$model` variable may still only have the data you put into it.

To get data added at the database level, you may need to call [`$model->refresh()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#refresh()-detail) in order for it to refresh the data in your local `$model` variable with the current data from the database.

In other words, try this:

```
public function actionAddgroup()
{
    $model = new Groups();
    $model->groupName=Yii::$app->request->post('groupName');

    $model->save();
    $model->refresh();
    return $model->id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function actionAddgroup()
{
    $model = new Groups();
    $model->groupName=Yii::$app->request->post('groupName');

    $model->save();  // a new row is inserted into user table
    return $model->getPrimaryKey();
}
```